# Editable checkbox in Page

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor

I have a Sitecore field of `checkbox type`. I am showing it in Experience Editor as below and is Editable :
[image]

My code of `Cshtml` is:
**`IsNavigable: @Html.Glass().Editable(Model,x=>x.IsNavigable)`**

How can I make the above `0 or 1` as a checkbox to `check` and `uncheck`? Also if checked it should retain that but can be editable to be unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

This is the case where you need to use Field editor button, basically you can define a field editor button in core database, you can define the fields you want to be edited, then associate this button with your rendering, following are the steps:

1. Switch to core database and navigate to this path: /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Custom Experience Buttons
2. Specify an icon, a header, Fields (the field(s) names pipe-separated
   you want to edit) and tooltip.
3. Switch back to master database and in Experience Editor Buttons navigate to your button and select it.

Now when you're in Experience Editor, you will find a button that you can use to edit the checkbox field, as example see below:

[image]

Comment: Point 3 above should be:
Switch back to master database, select the rendering that shows that checkbox, and modify the field "Experience Editor Buttons" to add the new experience button you created in step 2. Now when you select that rendering in the experience editor, you should be able to click on your new experience editor button that should show the checkbox that you can check/uncheck.